# How to reread CWL files without restarting TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

Is there any way to reread CWL files (after I've modified them) without restarting TeXstudio?

It takes long to restart TeXstudio.

Comment: Maybe you can open an issue in https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues to directly ask the maintainers of TeXstudio directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no", as of Jun 24, 2020. There is no way. https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1139